# Loading bundled static assets in React Native WebView

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a React Native project where I'm trying to bundle some pre-generated HTML, JS, and CSS with the application, and have a WebView render the web assets using the `react-native-community/react-native-webview` library. I can load the index.html file just fine, but it won't load the other assets because it seems to be pointing to the wrong path. I've tried using `baseUrl` but it doesn't seem to work.

My React Native code looks like this:

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: './assets/index.html' }}
  allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  originWhitelist={["*"]}
  mixedContentMode='always'
/>
```

And then as part of the build process, my assets directory has this structure:

```
ios
|- assets
  |- index.html
  |- js
    |- main.js
  |- css
    |- main.css
```

I have this as part of the Copy Bundle Resources step in Xcode, so the assets directory is included with the ios app bundle.

Inside index.html is this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Going back to the original question, when I run this application, I can see the "Hello world!" so that tells me the HTML is loading, but the CSS and the JS files don't load because as far as I can tell it's trying to load from `file:///assets/js/main.js` instead of being relative to the app bundle location. Is there any way I can get this to work as desired?

I'd really, really like to avoid having to change the script src from `/js/main.js` if at all possible. The actual application I'm building auto-generates these files from a separate react project I have.

---

I have a sample minimal project that demonstrates this issue here:
https://github.com/jabbawookiees/psyduck

You can just clone this project then run the following if you want to try fixing it:

```
yarn install
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
yarn run react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: please how did u manage it ?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was bundling a web server with my iOS app and serving the resources from there.

https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server